# Passar parâmetro de uma rota para outra

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-rotas

Preciso pegar uma variável da url e redirecionar com o parâmetro para outra function

```
Route::get('doacao/{id}', function(Request $request){
   return Redirect::route('escolha/doacao')->with('id',$request->id);
});
```

Redirecionando para essa outra rota para pegar o parâmetro na função @retornaAssociado:

```
Route::get('escolha/doacao', ['as' => 'escolha/doacao', 'uses' => 'Site\CadastroController@retornaAssociado']);
```

Tentei várias maneiras para pegar o id dentro da função, mas nao consegui. Preciso de duas rotas pois não quero que apareça o id na url quando retornar a view.

```
public function retornaAssociado(Request $request){
   $data = $request->all(); 

   return view('layouts/pagamento')->with('id', $data['id']);  

}
```

Comment: Dá algum erro ?

Comment: @DiegoSouza não, simplesmente envia nulo

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Será que o correto não seria passar uma variável `$id` para capturar o parâmetro da rota?

```
Route::get('doacao/{id}', function(Request $request, $id){
   return Redirect::route('escolha/doacao')->with('id',$id);
});
```

Aí na rota a seguir, para capturar esse parâmetro, você precisa pegar o valor que está em `session`.

```
public function retornaAssociado(Request $request){

   return view('layouts/pagamento')->with('id', session('id'));  

}
```

Quando você usa o método `with` de `Redirect`, você está dizendo para o laravel armazenar os dados num flash de sessão. Eu creio que esse não seja o caso viável, pois se você atualizar a páginas, esses dados vão sumir. Isso porque o [flash, depois de usado, é removido da sessão](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/session#flash-data)

Eu acho que seria melhor você adicionar um parâmetro opcional na segunda rota, pra receber esse parâmetro de outra url, mas se não receber, a página é exibida também normalmente.

Assim:

```
Route::get('escolha/doacao/{id?}', ['as' => 'escolha/doacao', 'uses' => 'Site\CadastroController@retornaAssociado']);

public function retornaAssociado(Request $request, $id = null){

   return view('layouts/pagamento')->with('id', $id);  

}
```

Se alguém acessar `escolha/doacao/1`, o valor de `$id` será `1`. Se acessar `escolha/doacao`, o valor será `NULL`.

Mas note também que é necessário, no ato de redirecionamento, você passar como parâmetro o `$id`, para que seja redirecionado para essa rota com o mesmo parâmetro:

```
Route::get('doacao/{id}', function(Request $request, $id){
    return Redirect::route('escolha/doacao', $id);
});
```

O código acima resultará em um redirect para `"escolha/doacao/{$id}"`. Assim, se alguém acessar `doacao/5`, será redirecionado para `escolha/doacao/5`. Mas não impede de a pessoa acessar `escolha/doacao` diretamente.

## Atualização

Se a intenção do autor da pergunta é redirecionar para outra url, ocultando o valor de `$id` passado em `doacao/$id`, eu sugiro a utilização de `session` (não estou falando do `with`, pois o valor é temporário).

Você poderia fazer:

```
Route::get('doacao/{id}', function(Request $request, $id){

   session('doacao.id', $id);

   return Redirect::route('escolha/doacao');
});
```

Para recuperar esse valor, basta chamar `session('doacao.id')`.

Comment: Tentei dessa forma também, mas ele não reconhece o parâmetro: Missing argument 1 for App\Http\Controllers\Site\CadastroController::retornaAssociado()

Comment: @scooby não esconde, na verdade você está dizendo que é opcional. Pode ou não pode ter o valor, entende?

Comment: Ah entendi, valeu.

Comment: Wallace, nesse caso existe alguma forma de enviar o parâmetro sem estar na url? pois dessa forma quando não tem parâmetro ele retorna nulo

Comment: a função parece ignorar o ->with('id',$id) e só enxerga o parâmetro da url

Comment: @scooby ao invés de usar `with`, você passa por parâmetro do `Redirect::route`.

Comment: @scooby agora que entendi. Você quer passar o parâmetro de forma "invisível" ao usuário?

Comment: Exatamente! não posso mostrar o id na url

Comment: dessa forma ele tb fica visível:     return Redirect::route('escolha/doacao',array( 'id' => $request->id ));

Comment: @scooby agora não entendo: Por que não pode mostra o ID na url, sendo que a url já vem de um id visível?

Comment: De qualquer forma, já respondi à sua curiosidade. Use `session`.

Comment: Faz um slug, usa token, usa hash, md5, bcrypt, sha1 ou pode usar session.

Comment: Pq eu mando essa url direto de uma função na controller com um redirect, mas obrigado pela ajuda vou procurar o session

Comment: @scooby olha, tudo bem. Você que sabe. Mas acho se o ID fica visível para o usuário, O Session é desnecessário. :p